# How to save and retrieve class object from NSUserDefaults swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver

I'm trying to save my array to NSUserDefaults. But my Array exist with struct.

```
struct MyData {
    var Text = String()
    var Number = Int()
}

var Data = [MyData]()
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28241185/5089484) and I tried to do this;

```
let Data2 = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(Data)
```

But this gives me this: `Cannot invoke 'archivedDataWithRootObject' with an argument list of type '([(TableViewController.MyData)])'`

Any advice?

Comment: Maybe you can convert your struct to string and save. On retrieval, you can create a struct back from the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift `structs` are not `classes`, therefore they don't conform to `AnyObject` protocol.

And Syntax for `archivedDataWithRootObject` is:

```
class func archivedDataWithRootObject(rootObject: AnyObject) -> NSData
```

Which means it only accept `AnyObject` type object and `struct` doesn't conform `AnyObject` protocol so you can not use `struct` here.

So just change `struct` to `class` and it will work fine.

**UPDATE:**

This way you can store it into `NSUserDefaults`.

**Tested with playGround**

```
import UIKit

class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name: String!
    var age: Int!
    required convenience init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
        self.name = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
        self.age = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("age") as! Int
    }
    convenience init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        if let name = name { coder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name") }
        if let age = age { coder.encodeObject(age, forKey: "age") }


    }

}

var newPerson = [Person]()
newPerson.append(Person(name: "Leo", age: 45))
newPerson.append(Person(name: "Dharmesh", age: 25))
let personData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(newPerson)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(personData, forKey: "personData")

if let loadedData = NSUserDefaults().dataForKey("personData") {
    loadedData
    if let loadedPerson = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(loadedData) as? [Person] {
        loadedPerson[0].name   //"Leo"
        loadedPerson[0].age    //45
    }
}
```