# How to store a custom array of objects using NSUserDefaults Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storing-data

I am a novice programmer who has started to learn Swift to make apps.

So my question is: "How can I store an array of my objects using NSUserDefaults". Originally, I was looking at [this question posted on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240848/how-to-save-an-array-of-objects-to-nsuserdefault-with-swift). However, I don't really understand exactly how they did it. After searching on youtube with really no success, I have no choice but ask a question on stack overflow. (I'm hesitant because people often vote my questions off as I'm a beginner asking stupid questions)

So here goes.

I am making a todo list using swift. I have one main class called Task Manager that contains an array of Task objects.

**Task Manager (Functionality)**

- Contains the array of tasks
- Saves and Loads data using NSUserDefaults in order to store the tasks

**Task  (Functionality)**

- Stores the name and description of a task
- Not sure if it should have anything else

So now, after looking at several online tutorials, here is what i have. (It  doesn't work)

**Task Manager: Raw Code**

```
//
//  TaskManager.swift
//  ToDoList
//
//  Created by Ronak Shah on 7/5/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 com.ShahIndustries. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

var taskMgr : TaskManager = TaskManager()


class TaskManager: NSObject{
    var tasks: [Task]? = [Task]()
    var time = 1 //debug, ignore

    override init(){
        super.init()

        let taskData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("tasks") as? NSData

        if let taskData = taskData {
            let taskArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(taskData) as? [Task]

            if let taskArray = taskArray {
                tasks = taskArray
            }

        }
    }

    func addTask(taskName : String, taskDescription : String){
        var newTask = Task(taskName: taskName , taskDescription: taskDescription)

        tasks!.append(newTask)

    }

    func getTaskAtIndex(index: Int) ->Task {
        return tasks![index]
    }


    func saveData() {
        let ud = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        ud.setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(taskMgr), forKey: "tasks")
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        if let dataTasks = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("tasks") as? [Task] {
            self.tasks = dataTasks
        }

    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        if let tasks = self.tasks {
            aCoder.encodeObject(tasks, forKey: "tasks")
        }
    }

    func loadData() {
        let ud = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if let data = ud.objectForKey("tasks") as? NSData {
            //not sure how to get the data
        }
    }
}
```

**Task: Raw Code**

```
//
//  Task.swift
//  ToDoList
//
//  Created by Ronak Shah on 7/5/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 com.ShahIndustries. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

class Task :NSObject{
    var name : String?
    var desc : String?

    init (taskName : String, taskDescription : String){
        self.name = taskName
        self.desc = taskDescription
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        if let dataDesc = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("desc") as? String {
            self.desc = dataDesc
        }

        if let dataTitle = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as? String {
            self.name = dataTitle
        }
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        if let name = self.name {
            aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
        }

        if let desc = self.desc {
            aCoder.encodeObject(desc, forKey: "desc")
        }
    }
}
```

So how might I store my array of tasks (named tasks in Task Manager)?

Comment: If you are looking to store data, for something like a TODO list. Which could possibly have an infinite amout of entries. I would store the data using CoreData. CoreData is designed to hold large amounts of data. CoreData is pretty easy to use/learn. If you plan to get into programming apps for IOS, a good working knowledge of CoreData will help. Do a search on youtube for CoreData tutorials, plenty will come up. You might even find one making a TODO list using CoreData :) Goodluck coding and enjoy the upvote ;)

Comment: Oh so NSUserDefaults is only for tiny amounts of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs say:

> For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects

There's `NSData` among the property list types. In order to convert you custom object to `NSData` you have to serialize it.

You are trying to implement the archiving step on `Task` and `TaskManager` objects which adds complexity. The easiest way to achieve your goal is to archive (convert to `NSData`) just `Task` objects and add them to an array before saving to the defaults. In order to do that you have to convert the `tasks` array of type `[Task]` to an array of type `[NSData]` It would look like this.

```
func saveData() {
    let tasksAsData = tasks.map { task in 
        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(task)
    }
    let ud = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    ud.setObject(tasksAsData, forKey: "tasks")
}
```

When you get the data back you have to convert `NSData` objects into `Task`s. You can do it in the following way.

```
func loadData() {
    let ud = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let data = ud.objectForKey("tasks") as? [NSData] {
        tasks = data.map { data in 
            return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data)
        }
    }
}
```

There you go! I think you can take it from here.

---

As a side note I am advising not to use `NSUserDefaults` for such purpose. The defaults are meant as a simple way of saving little pieces of (usually) unstructured data. When you add more properties to your tasks it is likely to get cumbersome (you'll probably serialize things like `image`, `date`, or `location`). It is not space efficient nor is it fast. I advise to take a look at other ways to persist data on iOS like `SQLite`, `Core Data`, `Realm` or many others.

Comment: thanks. sorry i meant to accept this sooner but i got busy