# How to save json data on userdefaults in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, swift4

[image]

This is my model class

```
class UserRoot : Mappable {
    var success : Bool!
    var user : UserDetails!
    var error = ""

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        success <- map["success"]
        user <- map["user"]
        error <- map["error"]

    }
}
```

after successfully login i want to save this data on user defaults so that when a user have to not give login credential again. Here is my code

```
class Default : NSObject{
    static func saveToSharedPrefs(user: UserDetails!) {
        let d = UserDefaults.standard
        if user != nil {
            d.set(Mapper().toJSONString(user, prettyPrint: false) , forKey: "USERDETAILS")
        } else {
            d.set(nil, forKey: "USERDETAILS")
        }
        d.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Mappable`? Based on a little searching,it looks like there are a couple of different third party frameworks that use that protcol/class name. Whenever you use a third party framework you should include its name in your question title so others who have knowledge of that framework see the question and are more likely to read/answer it.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't store large/complex data into `UserDefaults`. It's meant for small bits of user settings. You could easily write your data to a plist in the documents directory, which would be a better way to do it.

Comment: Okay sir thanks for your valuable advise will keep it in my mind.

Comment: i can save the total userlist in plist sir? @DuncanC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Make sure your model class is inherited from `NSObject` class otherwise it will crash at run time.

To store data:

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: <Your model class>)
UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "userDetails")
```

To retrive and convert data back

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userDetails") as? Data {
    if let dict = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? <Your model class> {
           print(dict)
     }
}
```

Comment: but it is not running sir

Comment: you need to convert if as per your model class here `as? [String: Any]` in getting back the data.

Comment: convert to what sir?

Comment: if let dict = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? <Your model class> { what will be in the "Your model class" ?

Comment: "Your model class" will be `UserDetails` class  and make sure it is inherited from `NSObject` like `class UserDetails: NSObject { .... }`

Comment: i have two class 
class UserRoot : NSObject, Mappable {
    var success : Bool!
    var user : UserDetails!
    var error = ""
    
    required init?(map: Map) {
        
    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        success <- map["success"]
        user <- map["user"]
        error <- map["error"]
        
    }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167818/discussion-between-mahendra-gp-and-gorib-developer).

Answer (score 3):

In swift 4 Better use **JSONEncoder** to encode your Swift object to JSON  and **JSONDecoder** to decode your JSON to Swift object, Confirm **Codable** protocol to your Model class before encode and decode. [You can follow this answer from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48438338/4644528)

Comment: sir no idea about codable

Comment: Start learning and using it, it will save your time and effort of JSON parsing. It is very easy to learn and implement. [Everything about Codable in Swift 4](https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999),   [Painless JSON Parsing with Swift Codable](https://medium.com/xcblog/painless-json-parsing-with-swift-codable-2c0beaeb21c1)

Comment: Okay sir @Kazi Abdullah Al Mamun

Comment: I agree with Kazi. Swift 4 includes built-in support for mapping your object graph back and forth to JSON. If you do a Google search on "Swift 4 Codable" you'll find several pages of tutorials. Ray Wenderlich's site usually has good content. Try this one, for example: https://www.raywenderlich.com/172145/encoding-decoding-and-serialization-in-swift-4

Comment: Okay sir @DuncanC

Answer (score 1):

You can use Data to store this json in the user defaults like this:

```
let myData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: myJson)
UserDefaults.standard.set(myData, forKey: "userJson")

let recovedUserJsonData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "userJson")
let recovedUserJson = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: recovedUserJsonData)
```

> Edit

you can not store mapper in NSUserDefault, you can only store  **NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary**.

`NSKeyedArchiver` converts your mapper into `NSData` which you can store into `userdefault`.

Comment: Okay.doing it accordingly

Comment: intead of ' Default.saveToSharedPrefs(user: self.userDetails)' now i am writing   let myData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: json)
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(myData, forKey: "userJson") is it okay?

Comment: @GoribDeveloper assuming `userDetails` is the object of `UserRoot` and `UserRoot` is inherited by `NSObject` .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167814/discussion-between-gorib-developer-and-dahiya-boy).

Answer (score 0):

Using ObjectMapper pod.

```
class GooglePlace : Mappable {

    var id = ""
    var addressTitle = ""
    var formattedAddress = ""
    var latitude : Double?
    var longitude : Double?

 required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        addressTitle <- map["name"]
        formattedAddress <- map["formatted_address"]
        latitude <- map["geometry.location.lat"]
        longitude <- map["geometry.location.lng"]
        id <- map["id"]
    }

}

var placesesSearchHistory : [GooglePlace]? = []

if let jsonString = placesesSearchHistory?.toJSONString(prettyPrint: true) {
//Store in UserDefaults
      UserDefaults.standard.set(jsonString, forKey: "addressSearchHistory")

} 


//retrieve from UserDefaults
 if let dataArrayString = (UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "addressSearchHistory")) as? String {

 if let dataObject = Mapper<GooglePlace>().mapArray(JSONString: dataArrayString)  {
                placesesSearchHistory = dataObject
            }
        }
```

Comment: In Swift 4+ all third-party JSON parsing libraries have become obsolete in favor of built-in `Codable` protocol. And `string(forKey` **does** return an optional string, the conditional *downcast* is redundant.