# Save an object in NSUserDefaults and Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm, nsuserdefaults

Is it possible to save an object in both **NSUserDefaults** and **Realm** (Swift) ?

I have found a problem in creating my Model since **NSUserDefaults** require the inheritance of `NSObject` and Realm requires the inheritance of `Object`.

Doing so , raised this error

```
Multiple inheritance from classes 'Object' and 'NSObject'
```

Comment: Why do you want to save it in this way? Save the value in the NSUserDefaults within the variable in object realm ex `myobject.id 
 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("id") as Int`

Comment: See this answer to save `Swift` object to `UserDefaults` https://stackoverflow.com/a/48438338/4644528

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Swift4's `Codable` protocol, you can save a custom class to `UserDefaults` without having to conform to the old `NSCoding` protocol.

```
class Team: Object, Codable {
    @objc dynamic var id:Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name:String = ""
}

let team = Team()
team.id = 1
team.name = "Team"
let encodedTeam = try! JSONEncoder().encode(team)
UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedTeam, forKey: "team")
let decodedTeam = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Team.self, from: UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "team")!)
```

This solves the problem of multiple inheritance, since your type doesn't need to inherit from `NSObject` anymore.